# How to access the sub keys of a key from a YAML file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

If we have a .yml file as below:

```
foo:
  key1: someValue1
  key2: someValue2
```

we can access its content by:

```
conf = YAML.load_file("config.yml")
```

and a value of a hash like:

```
conf.fetch('foo')['key1'] #=> "someValue1"
```

How can we access the key whose value is `'someValue1'`?

Or

Better to ask: how to access keys of `'foo'` (key1 and key2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
conf.fetch('foo').keys
```